# Как правильно реализовать систему банов и разделение на роли?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Разрабатываю небольшой веб-проект. Начал с проектирования БД. Столкнулся с рядом проблем. Одна из них: как правильно организовать систему банов, как реализовать  разделение на роли. Вот моя предварительная диаграмма бд http://dbdesigner.net/designer/schema/23655 ( если вам покажется, что диаграмма пуста, то подвигайте ползунки) 
К системе банов и разделению на роли имеют отношения 4 таблицы: 1. users ( все пользователи, включая админов и модераторов). Для нас сейчас важны два ее поля id ( уникальный номер пользователя) и roleID ( определяет роль пользователя, является внешним ключом, указывает на поле id таблице Roles). 2. Roles - роли пользователей. Просто содержит возможные роли админ, модер, юзер.... 3. UserBans - таблицу, содержащая все баны пользователей (активные и не активные). Т.е. когда пользователь будет проходить авторизацию, в данной таблице будут выискиваться действующий ограничения). Поле userID указывает id пользователя, на которого наложен бан. Autor - так же ведет к таблице users, но указывает админа/модера, который наложил бан. Пробовал экспортировать sql, ms sql server не может его выполнить, выдает сообщение о возможном зацикливании. 4. BanTypes - типы банов. Вопрос: правильно ли мое решение? если нет, то как сделать лучше? да и вообще, как теперь создавать таблицы, если ms sql не нравится две два ключа с одной таблицы к другой?

Comment: Mssql мне на вашей схеме по русски написал: "Укажите ON DELETE NO ACTION или ON UPDATE NO ACTION". Уберите каскадный update/delete с этих форедженов. если будет нужен каскад - реализуете триггерами с учетом возможного зацикливания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернативный вариант: разделить все возможные действия на уровни. Чем больше уровень, тем больше возможных действий. Писать это число в сессию вместе с логином. Когда юзер пытается сделать действие - проверять, какой уровень доступа записан в сессию этого пользователя и сравнивать с тем, какой уровень прописан в действие. А для логов вести одну отдельную табличку.

Comment: Я возможно путано изложил свой вопрос,  и потому вы так странно отвечаете. Ваш вариант никак не является альтернативным. Я ведь спрашивал о способе хранения, а вы мне уже о реализации.

Comment: Возможно я не достаточно внимательно прочитал Ваш вопрос. По-сути проблемы с двумя ключами могу сказать, что в ms sql под asp.net когда столкнулся с подобной проблемой, то решить конфликт ключей не смог и один из них убрал перестроив структуру таблиц. Но я джуниор и у меня мало опыта. Вероятно кто-нибудь из старожилов знает более разумный способ решения.